# IIS 8.5 Mystery of pages not being logged

Tags: asp.net, iis

I was troubleshooting a customer's problem on one of our internal websites.
The customer said they could not answer a question (fill out a form and save).

The website is a 2 node web farm labeled web1 and web2 running windows 2012.

I also log every page hit to help for troubleshooting purposes by sending the name of the page into a row in the database.

I looked at the page history for the customer and found the order odd. The site has a wizard that it takes the user through and it did not do this.

The customer was hitting web2 according to the database.
I went to look at the IIS log for web2 and the pages that the customer was logging were not present in the IIS Log.

There were hits from another application which does not have authentication at similar time so the server must have been up at the time. I also noted that the other site was being crawled at the time by the BING bot.
I don't have a log of the person throwing an error (I log this page also).

Does anyone know how a page could be served in IIS, sending a record to the DB,  but not be written to the log? I think I can figure out how this happened I can figure out why the customer had an issue.

Thanks

Comment: Check the C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\W3***1 Logs for all connection requests. What is the logging tool you are using?

Comment: We have the actual logs somewhere else for IIS but I checked for other items logged in the folder and nothing for the time in question. I haven't been using a log tool, just notepad. But I have started to looking through other logs not directly related to IIS to see if I can find another clue.

Comment: Have you checked the IIS logs on web1?

Comment: Wireshark the 2 servers and have the user do the request. I don't know how isolated you can get the traffic. Something has to be on Web2 that there was a response given.

Answer (score 0):

The mystery is that the raw logs have a GMT timestamp and I didn't account for the calculation when I compared it to my database log. 
Sorry for being an idiot.